# 50 Fathoms Quake Spell Effect

Tags: savage-worlds, 50-fathoms

How big a hole does the Quake spell in 50 Fathoms produce? The description says that those who make their save, cling to the sides and may climb out.

Comment: does the spell give any indication at all of the area it effects?  50 Fathoms is one of the few settings I don't have for SW, otherwise I would check myself :)

Comment: The spell has a Large Burst Template area of effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Savage Worlds uses a small, medium and large burst template. They measure 3, 4, and 5 inches in diameter. Page 62 of the first edition rules states one inch on the battle map is equal to 2 yards. Using that, the Quake spell, which uses the large template, produces a hole about 10 yards in diameter.

Comment: Does that mean the hole is 5 yards deep?

Comment: That's what I would say. If the blast template is a sphere then it makes sense.